# Android Service (In its own thread) dies when app is killed then restarts

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, bind

I've been struggling with this question for weeks now. I'm fairly new to Android, hopefully you can give me a hand.

I have this service which runs on a separate thread than the app's. Essentially, the user instructs it to start, and it should stay alive either until the user tells it to stop or until it has served its purpose - it schedules its own destruction (stop) when needed. The service needs to stay alive as it holds important priority-related information, so I can't simply turn to the alarm manager to revive it when needed - though I do use alarm manager for other purposes. I'm having two problems:

- First of all, when the user closes the application (by holding the middle button and close the app) the service is destroyed, which means, I lose my data (I'm assuming it gets destroyed as it reboots automatically).
- Secondly, it restarts itself, thus causing the data to be re-loaded hence, I lose the data.

As for the activity, its binding to the server through:

```
private void startService() {
    startService(new Intent(this, CES.class));
    bindService(new Intent(this, CES.class), mConnection, 0);
}
```

Finally, the relevant (or at least the ones I find relevant) methods in the Service:

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new ICESInterface.Stub() { ..... }
@Override
public void onCreate() {
//keeps being called thus I lose my data }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    //return START_STICKY;
}
```

Let me know if there is more data/information you need.

Comment: I suggest you to remove the onStartCommand method if you use it just to return START_STICKY or the super.onStartCommand(...). The reason is that this is automatically done by Android in the upper class (if you look at the source code you'll see).

Comment: If an Application is actually *killed* (vs an Activity simply being destroyed) everything in that process dies.  A service that is supposed to still be running will then get re-created in a new process.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The service is running on a separate thread already.

Comment: You had already mentioned that but it doesn't matter - when a process is killed, so are all of its threads.

Answer (score 2):

By returing a binder in onBind you are creating a **bound** service, which means it is "bound" to your app. This means that it get's destroyed when you app does, that explains the home button destroy. You should be returning **null** for a background service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
//keeps being called thus I lose my data
 }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

You should start your service with [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) flag, so that if the OS destroys your service when running low on resources, it will later recreate it.

Prior to destroying your service, Android will call `public void onLowMemory()`, there save any data you need so that when it restarts your service, you will be able to do your task again.

**EDIT:** As per your comment, you would like a service that is running in the background and also allows binding. You can do that if you call the `startService()` method before any `bindService()` calls are made... this will effectively make your service a started service instead of bound. In that case you are able to return a `IBInder` and bind to it.

There is a really, really good article [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: I'm using it to return a binder for AIDL communication.

Comment: Doesn't matter why-  when a bound service no longer has any clients bound to it, the bound service is destroyed.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve the AIDL part then? Meaning, have it run indefinitely but still allow AIDL communication - since I can't return the binder /stub.

Comment: are you sure you need AIDL? AIDL make your service "public"

Comment: I thought I could do it as this part of the documentation confused me (clearly only one of the options is supported at the same time):"Although this documentation generally discusses these two types of services separately, your service can work both ways—it can be started (to run indefinitely) and also allow binding. It's simply a matter of whether you implement a couple callback methods: onStartCommand() to allow components to start it and onBind() to allow binding."

Comment: Well the service runs in a separate thread, hence, its the best approach - I really dislike the Messenger approach. Being public is not a problem, as I'll just limit the access based on the package keys.

Comment: Yes you can do it that way, but I wasn't sure if you needed the AIDL. That's why I asked you.

Comment: @BojanKseneman- Problem is, as stated in the first thread, I'm already doing it `private void startService() {
    startService(new Intent(this, CES.class));
    bindService(new Intent(this, CES.class), mConnection, 0);
}`

And still, the problem persists

Comment: I have seen it, I found out the problem:
Issue is, as soon as I call unbindService (even if I haven't called bindService), regardless of how I started the service, it kills the service, and later on it forces it to restart (even though its in START_NOT_STICKY and there are no other calls to startService). Can't figure out how to prevent it

Comment: Maybe calling start and right after that bind isn't the best idea. Are you absolutely sure that the onStartCommand is called before onBind? I'd try adding a delay. Also in your onStartCommand make sure to return START_STICKY

Comment: Ignore the " and later on it forces it to restart (even though its in START_NOT_STICKY and there are no other calls to startService)" as the behaviour is removed, pretty sure it was due to several startService calls.
As for your suggestion, I don't want it to auto restart because if I do, it just starts with empty data, so no point. I'll try the binding after.

Comment: None of this is going to stop the Service from being killed along with the rest of the process hosting it - all you will possibly achieve is to control the restart behavior.